# Semantic Issue: No setter method 'setisSelected:' for assignment to property

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to `Objective-C`, in fact it's been couple of hours since I have started learning it.

I am currently watching latest lectures from Stanford about iOS development, and in the second lecture Hegarty starts adding a basic button which gets selected upon clicking. Pretty basic stuff, but I can't figure out what's causing this error in my `XCode`, whereas the same code runs fine in the lecture video.

Here's the error message:

```
CardGameViewController.m
    Semantic Issue
     No setter method 'setIsSelected:' for assignment to property
```

This is my CardGameViewController.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CardGameViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

This is my `CardGameViewController.m` file:

```
#import "CardGameViewController.h"

@interface CardGameViewController ()

@end

@implementation CardGameViewController

- (IBAction)flipCard:(UIButton *)sender
{
    sender.isSelected  = !sender.isSelected;
}

@end
```

I am using XCode version 4.6.3, building a single view iPhone app, running it in iPhone 6.1 Simulator.

One difference I've observed in property `isSelected` in the video from mine is that in the video the `isSelected` is inherited from `UIControl`, whereas in my code the small documentation that comes up when alt-click says it's inherited from `UITableViewCell` instead.

I think that might be the reason behind this error, but don't know what those terms mean.

Can anybody help me with this issue? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not uncommon for `BOOL` values for a particular `@property` to use a slightly different method pattern, whereby the setter is `-set<property>:` and there's an alternative getter for `-is<property>`, which can cause some confusion when accessing through properties or `KVC`.

In this case, as @shem points out, the property you're looking for is `selected`, even though it's exposed in the API as `-isSelected` if you were to send a message to it, such as `[sender isSelected]`.

You can see this if you look in the declaration for the property in `UIControl` (as `UIButton` is a subclass of `UIControl`):

```
@property(nonatomic, getter=isSelected) BOOL selected
```

Note that it overrides the `getter`, indicating that the messages used to implement the `selected` property are actually `-setSelected:` and `-isSelected`.   In the end, though, this does not affect how you access the property when using dot notation, it's always just `sender.selected`.

This is really only important when looking at sample code that uses the method calls and then implementing using the properties.

Comment: wow! that was very informational. :)

Many thanks for telling about default getters!

Answer (score 4):

It's `selected` and not `isSelected` :

```
- (IBAction)flipCard:(UIButton *)sender
{
    sender.selected  = !sender.selected;
}
```

Comment: wow... what a stupid mistake I did there...

Many thanks my friend, for taking the pain to point out such a stupid mistake! :)

Comment: @ForbiddenOverseer it's not as uncommon as you might think, and I wouldn't call it stupid.  The problem stems from differences between the method selector patterns and the properties, and when co-mingling them (or working with older tutorials), it can be confusing.

Comment: @gaige is right, it's really confusing in the beging. really good explanation there!

Comment: @shem: I think gaige's answer is more informational to newbies like me. Your answer is already voted more, so I am accepting his answer instead. Hope you don't mind that. Thanks to both of you again!

Comment: Actually it should be sender.selected = !sender.isSelected; the property has a getter attribute, but I think you may be able to use the normal getter instead of the getter attribute version as well, which seems wrong to me, but there you go.